# Can no longer get domain class name using obj.domainClass

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In a Grails 2.2.4 I created some maps that were named based on the names of my domain classes.  My domain classes were...

```
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

... and my maps were named...

```
def my_Foo_Map
def my_Bar_Map
def my_Baz_Map
```

I then had a function that would dynamically get the correct map based on the domain class of the object being passed in...

```
private def getMap(def obj) {
    this."my_${obj.domainClass.name}_Map"
}
```

If an object with the `Foo` domain class were passed in the `my_Foo_Map` would be returned.

In Grails 3 I get a missing property exception telling me `domainClass` is not a property of `Foo`.  Why can I no longer access the domain class name the way I did in Grails 2.2.4.  What is the fastest way to get that name in Grails 3?